# Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be an injective function. Let $S$ and $T$ be subsets of $A$. Prove that if $f(S)\subseteq f(T)$, then $S\subseteq T$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Here is my proof:

let $x \in S$

$f(x) \in f(S)  $

$f(x) \in f(T)  $

$x \in T  $

$S \subseteq T$

I'm pretty sure I had to use the fact that f is injective somewhere, but I don't know how. Thanks!

Comment: This is supposed to be an if and only if proof.  You seem to be only proving the forward direction at the moment.  You have an error moving from $f(x)\in f(T)$ to $x\in T$.  Why should this be true?  Consider a counterexample where $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is the constant function $f(x)=1$ for all $x$.  Then $f([0,\infty))=\{1\}$ and $f(-1)=1$ despite $-1\not\in[0,\infty)$.  (*Further hint, you said yourself "I'm pretty sure I had to use the fact that $f$ is injective somewhere"*)

Answer (score 1):

When I was stuck in a proof often used to decompose the main statement, translating it in it's by-definition-meaning.
What does it mean $f(x)\in f(T)$? Then you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$f(S) \subset f(T)$:

$y \in f(S) \rightarrow y \in f(T)$.

For $y \in f(S)$, there is a $s \in S$ with $y=f(S).$

For $y \in f(T), $ there is $t \in T$ with $y=f(t).$

Since $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective, $S,T \subset A$,

$\rightarrow:$

$s=t,$  I.e.

the element $s\in S$ is equal to the element $t \in T$,

hence, $s=t \in T$$.

Do we get every $s \in S$ to conclude that $S\subset T$?